# APICTL shows an error when deploying an API

Tags: jenkins, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline where a user would create a resource from a swagger definition that he pushes to github, triggering the Pipeline to deploy it on the API Manager but I keep getting the following error :

```
Error...  stat /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_pipeline/apis/SwaggerPetstore-1.0.0: no such file or directory
```

This is my pipeline definition, I've been stuck with this for days now and don't know what to do

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        node {
            label 'node'
        }
    }
    environment { 
        PATH = "/root/apictl:$PATH"
    }
    options {
        buildDiscarder logRotator( 
                    daysToKeepStr: '16', 
                    numToKeepStr: '10'
            )
    }

    stages {

        stage('Setup Environment for APICTL') {
            steps {
                sh """#!/bin/bash
                ENVCOUNT=\$(apictl get envs --format {{.}} | wc -l)
                if [ "\$ENVCOUNT" == "0" ]; then
                    apictl add env dev  --apim https://am.wso2.com  --registration https://am.wso2.com  --token https://websub.am.wso2.com/token -k
                fi
                """
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy APIs To "Dev" Environment') {
            steps {
                sh """

                apictl set --export-directory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_pipeline

                apictl set --vcs-deployment-repo-path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_pipeline
                apictl set --vcs-config-path /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/gitconfig

                apictl get envs

                apictl login dev -u admin -p admin -k

                apictl vcs deploy -e dev -k --verbose
                """
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What do you have in your VCS?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the steps mentioned under **"stage('Deploy APIs To "Dev" Environment')"** in your script are incorrect. Refer to the complete set of steps mentioned in the document [1] (The document is for APIM 4.1.0 and apictl 4.1.x. If you are using APIM 4.0.0 and apictl 4.0.x please refer [2]).

These documents contains a section named **"Promoting APIs in a Git repository to upper environments via CI/CD"** [3], which explains which commands that you should use to perform apictl vcs related tasks. Another important thing is, that you should make sure to install git in your running environment.

Apart from the above facts, I can see you have not done setting the source repository (*apictl set --vcs-source-repo-path path/to/Source*) or not executed *apictl vcs init*.

Trying the correct set of steps as mentioned in the documentation will solve your problem.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/cicd-using-cli/#step-1-prepare-the-environments

[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/cicd-using-cli/#step-1-prepare-the-environments

[3] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/cicd-using-cli/#a-promoting-apis-in-a-git-repository-to-upper-environments-via-cicd

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check my script as soon as possible and come back if it doesn't work